# How to create an Instagram insights page in Android?

Tags: android

How to create an Instagram insights page animation in Android?

If there is a library for that please send the link

Instagram insights page video:
[Instagram insights video](https://upinja.com/up/video-2020-05-03-16-31-36.mp4)

Thank's alot

[image: Instagram insights]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These UI elements are called [BottomSheets](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom). They are developed by Google.

You can refer these third-party libraries or above:

[SuperBottomSheet](https://github.com/andrefrsousa/SuperBottomSheet)

[BottomSheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet)

[BottomSheet](https://github.com/AndroidCodility/BottomSheet)

[CustomBottomSheetBehavior](http://%20https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior)